# How can bundle multiple files to one module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, module, typescript2.0

I am trying to bundle multiple classes and interfaces to one module that can be used. But it is not working...

I have the following folder structure:

```
sources
    |- test
        |- package.ts
        |- Class11.ts
        |- Class12.ts
        |- subtest
            |- Class21.ts 
            |- Class22.ts
            |- package.ts
```

Later i want to use it like the packages in java.

```
import * from "test";
import { Class21 } from "test.subtest";

let c11 = new Class11();
let c12 = new Class12();
let c21 = new Class21();
let c22 = new test.subtest.Class22();
```

Is it possible to build modules in TypeScript which exports the classes/modules and interfaces that i can use it as described above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export the contents you want to be *packaged* in your package.ts files. For example:

In your `test/package.ts`:

```
export {Class11} from "./Class11";
export {Class12} from "./Class12";
// OR if you want to export everything
export * from "./Class50";
```

And use it like:

```
import * as testPackage from "./test/package";
import { Class11, Class12 } from "./test/package";

let c11 = new Class11();
let c12 = new testPackage.Class12();
```